# Select rows at same index from two different tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

thanks in advance for checking out my question. I have two html tables in which I want to select table rows from and push into an array. Table one's Id is #name and table two's id is #name2. This is the function to hold the ctrl key down and toggle the row to push into the array. I'm trying to write the function so if I ctrl+click a row in one table it applies to the same index's row in the other table.

```
function rowSelect(element){
var self = this;
self = 0;
var isCtrlDown = false;

element.on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    if(!isCtrlDown)
        return;
    tr.toggleClass('ui-selected')
})

$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    isCtrlDown = (e.which === 17)
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    isCtrlDown = !(e.which === 17)
});

self.getSelectedRows = function(){
    var arr = [];
    element.find('.ui-selected').each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).find('td').eq(0).text())
    })

    return arr;
}

return self;


}

  window.myElement =rowSelect($('#name'))
  window.myElement = rowSelect($('#name2'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the easiest way to do it is just to toggle that class on both rows at the same time. Just get the index of the clicked one, then select rows by index and toggle them both at once.

```
element.on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    if(!isCtrlDown)
        return;
    $('tr:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').toggleClass('ui-selected');
})
```

This solution ensures that both rows are being toggled together always, then selecting the elements by class will get them both or neither.

Also, if you go like:

```
rowSelect( $('#name, #name2') )
```

you can attach the events to both tables at once.

Comment: thanks! I ended up adding $('tr:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')').toggleClass('ui-selected'); because it was highlighting the previous row.

Comment: I spent a week working on this issue before re-phrasing my Stackoverflow query and discovering this answer.  Simple and elegant!  Thanks!